# How to handle event with state change avoiding renders

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with mouse event "mouseover" in react.
On each call I have to update the state and pass this value to another component.

```
const [posX, setPosX] = useState(0)
...

<Parent onMouseOver={e=> setPosX(e.target.offsetX)}>
  <Children offset={posX} />
</Parent>
```

So my question is how can I avoid re-render parent component on update the state?

Comment: You can't. The presence of the `useState` hook in that component, will trigger a re-render irregardless from where you will call `setPosX`. Though if you mean `<Parent ... />` in your example and not the enclosing *unnamed* component, then the re-render might be avoided by using a constant callback for `onMouseOver` prop (e.g. use `useCallback`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `useRef` (from react). Simply store the state you don't want to cause a rerender on the parent as a `ref`.

```
const posX = useRef(null);
...

<Parent onMouseOver={e=> posX.current = e.target.offsetX}>
  <Children offset={posX.current} />
</Parent>
```

Comment: Look here => https://playcode.io/react/
If I'll use ref the value will not be updated
```
const App = () => {
  const pos = useRef({x: 0, y: 0})

  return <h1 onMouseOver={e => {
    pos.current = {x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY}

  }}>Hi! Try edit me {pos.current.x}</h1>; 
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and it seems that  `e.target.offsetX` doesn't exist, however it exists on `e.nativeEvent.offsetX`. `useRef` might not be helpful here... can you describe the use-case better?